# UITableViewCell setting text

Tags: iphone

I am creating sample hello world application. The code is below. How can i removed the

warning at c[cell setText:@"Hello World"]; in the code below as it deprecated.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

[cell setText:@"Hello World"];
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

set cell label text

```
cell.textLabel.text = @"Hello World";
```

and detail label text

```
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"yourText";
```

Answer (score 3):

There's also more Objective-C way of doing that:

```
[[cell textLabel] setText:@"Hello World"];
```

and detail label text:

```
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:@"Hello World"];
```

Comment: This is actually less Objective-C way. Dot notation was introduced later and for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3.0 its should be

```
 cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell textLabel is deprecated now.

iOS 15+ should use:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "acme")
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "Hello World"
    cell.contentConfiguration = content
    return cell
}
```