# Cant set text for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UIViewController` with `tableView`, connected through delegate. When view loaded firstly, it launches loading data with `AFNetworking`. After loading finished, it sends notification to reload data. However, i encounter very strange bug. When i force `tableView` to reload, for some reason i cant set text for their labels, even when i have actually data. Here is storyboard:

[image]

And there is actual code. This code called when we recieve notification (after we got data from server, and array filled with new data):

```
#pragma mark - Notification Center

-(void)loadingFinished: (NSNotification*) notification{

    NSLog(@"Recieved notify");

    /* Перезагружаем таблицу */

    isDataLoaded = YES;

    NSLog(@" find 2 %@", [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:1]valueForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog(@" find 3 %@", [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:2]valueForKey:@"title"]);


    [self.spotlightTableView reloadData];

}
```

In CellForRow... :

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"Called once? ");

    // Инициализация ячейки


    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!isDataLoaded){
        NSLog(@"called no bool");
   cell.titleLabel.text = @"No data";
        cell.dateLabel.text = @"No date";
    }   else {
        NSLog(@"called with b00l");
        [cell.myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1]valueForKey:@"standardImage"]]];
        cell.titleLabel.text = [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1]valueForKey:@"title"];
        cell.dateLabel.text = [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1]valueForKey:@"created_at"];

    }

    NSLog(@"title - %@", [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1]valueForKey:@"title"]);
    NSLog(@"created_at0 - %@", [[self.detailDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row +1]valueForKey:@"created_at"]);


    return cell;
}
```

And there is strange thing: in table view i could see images loaded (in imageView), but i can only see text

```
 cell.titleLabel.text = @"No data";
 cell.dateLabel.text = @"No date";
```

[image]

So, chunk of code that passed in else statement, after isLoaded check is executed, but why i cant see text? I even tried fill it with fake text, but still, i can only see first output (when data isn't loaded).

Note: MyCell is custom class that i also use in another controller (with same identifier in StoryBoard).

NSLog Output is:

```
2016-01-25 14:57:01.894 MedApp[6056:159310] Recieved notify
2016-01-25 14:57:01.894 MedApp[6056:159310]  find 2 quis turpis vitae
2016-01-25 14:57:01.894 MedApp[6056:159310]  find 3 quis turpis vitae
2016-01-25 14:57:01.895 MedApp[6056:159310] Called once? 
2016-01-25 14:57:01.895 MedApp[6056:159310] called with b00l
2016-01-25 14:57:01.896 MedApp[6056:159310] title - quis turpis vitae
2016-01-25 14:57:01.896 MedApp[6056:159310] created_at0 - 2015-12-19 21:00:00
2016-01-25 14:57:01.897 MedApp[6056:159310] Called once? 
2016-01-25 14:57:01.897 MedApp[6056:159310] called with b00l
2016-01-25 14:57:01.897 MedApp[6056:159310] title - quis turpis vitae
2016-01-25 14:57:01.898 MedApp[6056:159310] created_at0 - 2015-12-19 21:00:00
```

Comment: I think this has already being addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974948/uitableviewcell-setting-text

Comment: Could you write all logs that you see?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban is [self.spotlightTableView reloadData]; called on main thread? If it isn't - try 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.spotlightTableView reloadData];
    });

Comment: @curious thank you but i still its not problem. When i create default uitableViewCell and set properties like above, it show me correct text. But i need to use my custom cell, not use default..

Comment: Are there another places where this code set?
   cell.titleLabel.text = @"No data";        cell.dateLabel.text = @"No date";

Comment: Carefully check your connections of those labels in which datas are not coming. @Evgeniy Kleban

Comment: @iPeter thank you, check my answer.

Comment: @curious thank you for help, please check my answer if you curious :)

Answer (score 0):

thank you for help, problem was in my custom class. When i try to avoid bug with reuse existing image (when firstly cell load old image in fraction on second, then new image) i wrote following in custom cell class implementation:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{

    // Для избежания подгрузки неверных изображений, когда таблица пытается загрузить ячейки которые уже были использованны.

    self.dateLabel = nil;
    self.titleLabel = nil;
    [self.myImageView cancelImageRequestOperation];
    self.myImageView.image = nil;
}
```

When i remove

```
self.dateLabel = nil;
self.titleLabel = nil;
```

everything went fine. Thanks!